# Simple js framework, DOM. (module style,like jQuery) Issue with adding methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frameworks

The task is to code simple framework in jQuery style, to solve this i've written code:

```
(function(window) {
window.smp=function smpSelector(selector) {
    return new smpObj(selector);
    }

function smpObj(selector) {
    this.length = 0;
    if (!selector ) {
        this.el = [];
        return this;
        }
    if(typeof selector == 'string'){
        if(selector[0]==='#'){
            this.el = [document.getElementById(selector.slice(1, selector.length))];
            this.length = 1;
            return this;
        } else if(selector[0]==='.'){
            this.el = document.getElementsByClassName(selector.slice(1, selector.length));
            this.length = this.el.length;
            return this;
        } else {
            this.el = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
            this.length = this.el.length;
            return this;
        }
    }
    else return null;           
}
window.smp.changeColor=function smpColor(color) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
            this.el[i].style.color = color;
    }
})(window);
```

And it's working OK. I can call like:

```
smp('div')
```

But then i've tried to add method:

```
window.smp.changeColor=function smpColor(color) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
            this.el[i].style.color = color;
    }
```

And it's not working properly.

```
  smp('div').changeColor('color')
```

(can't call like this )
I'll be grateful, if someone can show me mistake.
I've used this article [article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you `return this` in `smpObj` function, `this` is the instance of `smpObj` not `window.smp` and there's no `changeColor` method for `smpObj`.

To make it work, you can do like this:

```
(function(window) {
  window.smp = function smpSelector(selector) {
    return new smpObj(selector);
  };

  function smpObj(selector) {
    this.length = 0;
    this.changeColor = function smpColor(color) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) this.el[i].style.color = color;
    };
    if (!selector) {
      this.el = [];
      return this;
    }
    if (typeof selector == "string") {
      if (selector[0] === "#") {
        this.el = document.getElementById(selector.slice(1, selector.length));
        this.length = 1;
        return this;
      } else if (selector[0] === ".") {
        this.el = document.getElementsByClassName(
          selector.slice(1, selector.length)
        );
        this.length = this.el.length;
        return this;
      } else {
        this.el = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
        this.length = this.el.length;
        return this;
      }
    } else return null;
  }
})(window);
```

then try

```
 smp('div').changeColor('red')
```

Comment: Oh, i'am bad.
Thanks a lot, Your answer solve the problem.
Really appreciate your help!

Comment: glad it helps :). Btw, can you mark my answer as correct answer? :)

Comment: Think i have one more question.
It's a little bit off-topic, but mb you'll answer.
Since i'am not a js-dev i don't know, is it ok to use cycle in my changeColor func? Or more flexible way  exists?

Comment: What do you mean by `cycle`? More detail please?

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) this.el[i].style.color = color;
I use it cause in this.el i have html collection or array.

Comment: Ah it's ok. But I think you don't need to set `this.length` manually here since you can use `this.el.length`
    `this.changeColor = function smpColor(color) {
      for (var i = 0, l=this.el.length; i < l; i++) this.el[i].style.color = color; 
      return this; // for chaining further operations
    };`